# Notebook instance cannot be reached for several days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

As it is described on the title, I cannot reach a notebook instance for 3 days continiously. I also have this issue occasionally.

Anytime I try, It prompts

> does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a
> different zone, or try again later.

And it never became available at all! Any suggestions? I thought to move instance to another region but I am afraid this issue can be encountered on other regions too which is not a solid solution at least.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try creating the instance in another region/zone.
It would also be useful to know in which zone are you trying to create the instance.
Zones like south-asia1-a/b/c (Mumbai) are always used at their full capacity and rarely have enough resources for creating new instances. There's another post with a similar situation, with a more detailed answer that may solve or find a workaround to your specific case [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1031541/is-google-cloud-mumbai-asia-south1-a-b-c-facing-issues-due-to-covid-unable-t). Please let me know if this solves your issue.